# Making Particle Explosion More Realistic in CreateJS

Tags: javascript, createjs, tweenjs

My goal is to create a semi-realistic particle effect, which basically will look like a confetti explosion.

The issues I'm having currently:

1. Easing - I've tried multiple different easing effects, but can't get it right. I'd imagine the particles to fly upwards quickly, hang at the top for a short time, then fall slowly.
2. Too linear - The particles move in obvious straight lines. Is there any way to make these seem like they're moving along a curved type path?
3. Rotation - I want the particles to rotate a bit, but when I add rotation tweens, it seems to rotate around a weird origin point. How would I make the particles rotate around their centers?

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k62rv30y/2/)

I've been using GSAP a lot recently, I was also wondering if there's a way to start a tween in the timeline before the previous one ends?

```
function init(){

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);

    var colors = [
      '#f44336', '#e91e63', '#9c27b0', '#673ab7', '#3f51b5',
      '#2196f3', '#03a9f4', '#00bcd4', '#009688', '#4CAF50',
      '#8BC34A', '#CDDC39', '#FFEB3B', '#FFC107', '#FF9800',
      '#FF5722', '#795548'
    ];

    for (i=0;i<300;i++){
      var particleSize = Math.floor(Math.random() * 14) + 4;

      var particle=new createjs.Shape();
      particle.graphics.beginFill(colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 17) + 1 ]).drawRect(
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) - 50 + canvas.width/2 - (particleSize/2),  // x
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) - 50 + canvas.height/2 - (particleSize/2),  // y
        particleSize, // w
        particleSize  // h
      );

      stage.addChild(particle);
      stage.update();

      var timeMove = Math.floor(Math.random() * 800) + 600,
          timeFall = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1600) + 300,

          moveX = particle.x + Math.floor(Math.random() * 401) - 200,
          moveY = particle.y - Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 1,
          fallY = particle.y - Math.floor(Math.random() * 400) + 1;

      createjs.Tween.get(particle, {loop: false})
        .to({x: moveX, y: moveY }, timeMove, createjs.Ease.quadOut)
        .to({x: moveX + (moveX/1.2), y: 600 }, timeFall, createjs.Ease.quadIn);
    }

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
}

init();
```

Comment: Tween is a great approach for particle effects. Usually you want to use math, gravity, acceleration, etc - not just a simple tween. Not saying Tween won't work, but there are definitely better ways to get what you want. Check out the "Sparkles" demo that is in the EaselJS GitHub. You can see this in action here: http://www.createjs.com/demos/easeljs/sparkles

Comment: @Lanny very helpful tip. It's something I'm new to, so I'm trying to read into it a bit. Especially wrapping my head around how the math works for it. I did my best to attach what I've read from demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/935wp4zw/

No matter what I've tried I can't get the "esplosion" from center point effect working, though. Also, the speed seems to not change no matter what I do.